# Text positioning in PDF file

Tags: pdf

I'm experiencing a real difficulty when trying to compute (tx,ty) position of text objects from a parsed PDF stream.

I have a following stream code:

```
BT
0.75 0.68 0.67 0.902 k
/GS0 gs
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.018 Tc 7.56 0 0 7.56 77.1871 528.3107 Tm
(Text line 1)Tj
-0.019 Tc 0 -1.917 TD
(Text line 2)Tj
-0.017 Tc 0 -2.917 TD
(HEADER)Tj
ET
q
43.167 489.881 7.56 7.56 re
W n
BT
/TT0 1 Tf
0 Tc 7.56 0 0 7.56 43.1671 491.7707 Tm
(INDEX)Tj
ET
```

When I open this PDF in some PDF reader, the HEADER and INDEX objects appear exactly next to each other, as they were in the same line.

However, when calculating HEADER's ty value from previous Tm (528,3107), I get 491,7657 which is 0,0050 lower than INDEX's ty (491,7707). In other parts of file the more text paragraph has the greater is this difference.

Basically what I do is multiply Tm's scaling factor (7,56) by TD's ty deltas. Obiously, I'am doing it wrong, but still - on the net there is little docs for dummies like myself...

So my question is - how to the other PDF readers interpret HEADER and INDEX ty values as equal, so they print it at the same ty?

Comment: Your measured difference of "0.0050" is in *points*, the default measurement system of a PDF. This is 1/600th of a millimeter, or, if you prefer, 1/15000th of an inch. You cannot zoom in far enough with Adobe's PDF viewers to clearly see the texts are *not* aligned.

Comment: Please provide the PDF in question for inspection if you suspect other reasons.

Comment: @Jongware Are you saying that there is nothing wrong with my calculations?

Comment: Without actually doing the same calculations: it looks okay to me. It would be something else if your results were *way* off. Also noteworthy: "Operations on real numbers [...] might use single-precision or double-precision floating-point numbers." (PDF Spec. 1.6)

Comment: You can't compare floating point numbers without using some delta of uncertainty. Floating point numbers are not exact and calculation always introduce some errors.

Comment: I have another quick question - what is the height of line inserted by using T* operator? Is it just the ty value of Tm's scaling factor, in this case 7,56?

Comment: See [the official reference](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdf/info) -- Table 5.5 in Adobe's PDF 1.7, Table 108 in the ISO-32000 specification.

Comment: @Jongware You mean text leading, but there is no TL operators in the stream, nor the font definition specifies Leading entry. Table 108 says that TD operator sets the leading too - so does it mean that if before T* there is 0 -1 TD then the leading value is 1?